# Please help me, How to show number five in my bash script?

Tags: bash, variables, math, logic

My Script

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo -n "number 1 : "
read bil1
echo -n "number 2 : "
read bil2
krng=$(echo $bil1 - $bil2 |bc -l |sed -e 's/^\./0./' -e 's/^-\./-0./');
echo " Your result : $bil1 - $bil2 = $krng "
```

if I input " `-1` " for `$bil1` and "`-6`" for `$bil2`,why the result is error ?

this is the visual

```
number 1 : -1
number 2 : -6
(standar_in) 1: syntax error
Your result : -1 - -6 =
```

I want

```
Your result : -1 - -6 = 5
```

how to show number `5` in my bash script

Comment: what is the objective of the script? subtract/add two numbers?

Comment: Then pls use `\`expr $num1 - $num2\``

Comment: it doesn't work. can you help me again..??

Comment: I posted an answer..try that out.

Comment: oh, I'm so sorry. I don't input " P " in expr . and it working. thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can let two numbers calculate by using keyword 'let'

e.g.
`i=1
j=2
let k=$i+$j or let k=$i-$j`

thus `$k=3` or `$k=-1`

Answer (score 1):

Since your objective is to substract two numbers, pls use the following...much cleaner and easier (I really do not see any reason to use `sed` for the problem).

```
read x
read y
echo "$x - $y =  `expr $x - $y`"
```

So, your above code can be simplified as:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "number 1 : "
read bil1
echo -n "number 2 : "
read bil2
krng=`expr $bil1 - $bil2`
echo " Your result : $bil1 - $bil2 = $krng "
```

The above method works only for integers...if you have floats, use the following..(this works for integers too)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "number 1 : "
read bil1
echo -n "number 2 : "
read bil2
krng=$(echo $bil1 - $bil2 | bc)
echo " Your result : $bil1 - $bil2 = $krng "
```

Comment: oh God.
sorry, it doesn't work if I input " -1 - 0.2 " , why the result is error?. please help me again..?? :(

Comment: would you please to help me ? :(

Comment: but I want to combine that command with expr . so, that result can show integers number and not integers number.

Comment: i am confused...what does `show integers number and not integers number.` mean?

Comment: You dnt use both,,,just use the later...it works for both integers and non-integers.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, no. If you are keen on using both, you can check the input and see if it is an integer or a float. And based on that, you can use either one. But, if you know your input is float, use the later...if input is integer, use the former...if you dnt know...i would say use the later, to be on the safe side. Hope your confusion is resolved :)